# Google startup script on custom image not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have launched a VM in GCP using a custom image from GCP console.
I have added a start-up script while launching the VM.

When I login into the VM, I have observed that my start-up script is not executed.
I have gone through the log file and observed the " No start-up script found" message in /var/log/syslog.

Note : Start-up scripts execute successfully for VM's launched using GCP default images.

Can any one help me on how to execute start-up scripts for VM's launched using custom images.

Comment: you wrote "added a start-up script while launching the VM". start-up scripts are run only after boot. are you sure your script was there when the vm was booting?

Comment: Is there any way to check my script is there or not while booting or after launching the VM. The same process I have followed with GCP default images..everything working fine.

Comment: you can always ssh to your vm and check

Comment: Could you attach two or three additional lines of the error found in  /var/log/syslog?

Comment: does your custom image include the [Linux Guest Environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment)? The guest environment is what allows the metadata server to communicate with the OS. Without it, the startup script wont be detected by your OS